# How to restrict file types being uploaded to Spring MVC3 Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

I am using Spring MVC3 to handle file upload for my web application. For now, I can restrict the file size being uploaded using the following configuration defined in my xml context file:

```
<beans:bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="200000"/> 
</beans:bean>
```

I have scoured the web for how to restrict the file type but to no avail. Most of the articles I found only teach how to restrict the file size not the file type.
Thank in advance for your help.

Answer (score 8):

Try performing the check/routing in your controller's request handler method:

```
@RequestMapping("/save")
public String saveSkill(@RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file) {   
        if(!file.getContentType().equalsIgnoreCase("text/html")){
            return "normalProcessing";
        }else{
            return "redirect: /some/page";
        }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that come from the client? Could easily be spoofed.

Answer (score 6):

You restrict file uploading by file types, you can extend `org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver` class. And add method to check file content-type or file type using `MultipartFile`.

Provide file types , those you want to restrict in configuration like -

```
 <beans:bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="200000"/> 
    <beans:property name="restrictFileTypes" value="html,pdf,..."/> 
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: Who would call that method which checks the file type?

Comment: @JavaTechnical This is registered as a bean, and spring framework will take care of it while  loading the file.

Comment: Can you configure per controller/request mapping?

Answer (score 5):

You can create a user defined method to do this check:

```
String fileExtensions = ".exe,.dmg,.mp3,.jar";
String fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
int lastIndex = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
String substring = fileName.substring(lastIndex, fileName.length());
```

And check the condition:

```
if (!fileExtensions.contains(substring.toLowerCase()))
    //reject logic
else
    //accept logic
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also check the Mime Type and according to that you can restrict the user to upload the files
JMimeMagic Library will be used here.

```
MagicMatch match = Magic.getMagicMatch(file.getBytes());
        System.out.println(match.getMimeType());
```